# How can I get from 'pyspark.sql.types.Row' all the columns/attributes name?

Tags: python, apache-spark, attributes, row, pyspark

I am using the Python API of Spark version 1.4.1.

My row object looks like this :

```
row_info = Row(name = Tim, age = 5, is_subscribed = false)
```

How can I get as a result, a list of the object attributes ?
Something like : `["name", "age", "is_subscribed"]`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you don't care about the order you can simply extract these from a `dict`:

```
list(row_info.asDict())
```

otherwise the only option I am aware of is using `__fields__` directly:

```
row_info.__fields__
```